# why i can't connect bootstrap to jsp in intellij?

Tags: css, jsp, hyperlink

[image: is this for path? should i add something to this?]

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="script"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>
```

Title

there is no error , but when i run program , css and script don't run and in view source when i click on link, i get 404 error

Comment: And what is your problem? "Cant connect" is not a good description, what errors are you hitting?

Comment: there is no error , but when i run program , css and script don't run and in view source when i click on link, i get 404 error